# java - checked exception for 'throws' in overridden method

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, overriding, throws

I was practicing exception handling mechanisms with method overriding in java...My code is as follows:

```
class base {
    void show() {    
        System.out.println("in base class method");    
    }
}

class derived extends base {
    void show() throws IOException {    
        System.out.println("in derived class method");
        throw new IOException();
    }
}

class my {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {
            base b = new derived();
            b.show();
        }    
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception occurred at :" + e);
        }   
    }
}
```

Showing an error :

[image: cmd window]

So, I corrected following:

```
void show() throws IOException{
```

and it is working correctly...

One more experiment I did :

```
void show() throws Exception{
```

but it was also showing an error:

[image: cmd window]

As I understand, this is because of an overridden method's `throws` clause should mention the exact checked exception in `throws` clause of super class method.

As in second case, if I write `IOException`'s superclass `Exception` in throws clause, it also shows an error.  why? Even if `Exception` is parent class of all exceptions.

I just experimented...what this error tells I don't know...

Can any one please explain what it says and what are the constraints for mentioning checked exception in `throws` clause of an overridden method?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Ignore what you read in my answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok...no problem..but can you say me if I declare only Exception in derived, could I declare IOException in super class? And please answer, not in comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two related errors in the sample:

1)
Your **base class** method provides the **"template"** or **basic criteria** for the **derived class** method.

So, the base class should declare a super-set i.e. either the same exception class or base exception class of the derived class. You cannot declare that it throws nothing, because then the criteria will not match.

So if your derived class method is like this:

```
class Derived extends Base {
    void show() throws IOException {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then base class method "must" be:

```
class Base {
    void show() throws /*Same or base classes of IOException*/ {
        //...
    }
}
```

So both of these work:

```
class Base {
    void show() throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

or

```
class Base {
    void show() throws Throwable {
        //...
    }
}
```

2) When you try the above, the overall declaration of your `show` method now becomes `throws Exception`. As a result, anyone who uses this `show` must catch that exception.

In your `main` method, you are catching `IOException`. This will no longer work, the compiler complains "ok you are catching the IOException, what about all the other possibilities from Exception?" This is the second error that you showed.

To fix this, change the `main` method catch to include `Exception` as declared in the base class:

```
class My {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            base b = new derived();
            b.show();
        }
        /* NOTE: CHANGED FROM IOException TO Exception */
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception occurred at :" + e);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: ok..but say me if I declare only Exception in derived, could I declare IOException in super class?

Comment: @krupalshah no, since the base class says "any IOException is allowed" to be thrown. So the derived class can only throw some sort of IOException to match that restriction.

Comment: so what is the criteria for declaring checked exception in throws clause of overridden method?

Comment: No, A derived class can only declare same OR child exception OR Runtime exception.

Comment: @krupalshah like I mentioned in my answer, any "more restrictive" version of the base declaration. So you can use either the same exception or derived classes of the base exception.

Comment: @Maas please explain in answer if you know...sometimes comments are skipped.

Comment: I know, if you want to know better follow this simple example. https://code.google.com/p/learn-java/wiki/OverridenMethod

Comment: @metacubed so, in second case, I exactly tried that as I mentioned in my question...I declared Exception in super class method(which is parent of IOException) and IOException in sub class overridden method...but it is also showing an error...why?

Comment: That is impossible... I will paste you similar code in Answer

Comment: @krupalshah that is another error entirely. It is coming from your `main` function catch. Because the base class now throws Exception, you also have to catch Exception, not IOException.

Comment: @krupalshah I'm editing my answer to include both situations.

Comment: @metacubed thank you..I will appreciate if you explain about this 'another error'..(really horror:-))

Comment: @krupalshah check now..,

Comment: @metacubed I will like to accept first then check:-)

Answer (score 1):

Overridden methods may contain only the same checked exceptions in their `throws` clause as the super-method, or derived types at most.

For example if you say

```
class Base {

    public void foo(int y) throws IOException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
class Derived extends Base {

    public void foo(int y) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

then your compiler will say that the `foo` method inside `Derived` is incompatible with the throws clause in its superclass.

The other way around works because if I say

```
class Base {

    public void foo(int y) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
class Derived extends Base {

    public void foo(int y) throws IOException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

it's OK.

Why.

Think about the usage of your methods. Java expects you to be using the method polymorphically such as

```
Base a = new Derived();
a.foo(3);
```

As such, the compiler will force you to catch the exception thrown by `foo` in your declared type of the variable (`Base`). So your code will become

```
Base a = new Derived();
try {
    a.foo(3);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

Therefore, the *subtype* of `Exception` you declared in the `Derived` type is OK with your code above (a catch for an `Exception` will work for any of its subtypes as well) and as such, Java will allow you to declare `IOException` in derived, because it will cause no worries later on.

Comment: say me if I declare only Exception in derived, could I declare IOException in super class?

Comment: That's the point. No, you can't. If you go the other way around, say you declare `Exception` in base and `IOException` in derived, then that's possible.

Comment: can you explain better in answer why?